# Use induction to prove that pegs in a line can be interchanged

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, induction, puzzle

I am looking into the following problem:

> Ten pegs of 2 colors are laid out in a line of 11 holes (5 black to
> the left, a hole, 5 white to the right).   I want to interchange the
> black and white pegs, but I am only allowed to move pegs into an
> adjacent empty hole or to jump over one peg into an empty hole. Can I
> make the interchange?

The configuration is like this (the space is the empty hole):

```
BBBBB WWWWW
```

I think I proved it can be done by induction and I wanted to make sure my induction proof is sane.
I start with $B=1$ and $W=1$ (denoting the numbers of black and white pegs).

```
B W  
 BW  
WB   
W B
```

So it is possible to make the swap for $B=1$ and $W=1$.
I also confirm that this is possible for $B=2$ and $W=2$

```
BB WW  //start  
B BWW  // move black to the right  
BWB W  // white jump's to the left  
BW BW  // move black to the right(inner was reversed)   
BWWB   // white jump's to the left  
BWW B  // move black to the right  
BW WB  // move white to the right (outer right reversed but move backwards)    
 WBWB  // jump black to the right   
W BWB  // move white to the left  
WB WB  // move black to the left (outer left reversed)  
WBW B  // move white to the left  
W WBB  // jump black to the right   
WW BB  // move white to the left
```

**Proof:**
**Base case:** For $B=1$ and $W=1$ we can interchange the pegs using only the valid moves.
**Inductive hypothesis:** I can interchange $B = N$ and $W = N$ pegs using only valid moves
**Inductive step:**
We have $B = N + 1$ and $W = N + 1$ pegs.

```
BBBBB...BBB WWW...WWWWW
```

We can interchange the inner $B=N$ and $B=N$ by inductive assumption. Hence we get:

```
BWWWW...WWW BBB...BBBBW
```

I.e. we are left with a misplaced peg (the $nth + 1$) at each side.
But we can move the $nth +1$ towards the center using valid moves as each one is just an application of the base case (subproblems of size $1$).
I.e.

```
BWWWW...WWW BBB...BBBBW  
B WWWW...WWWBBB...BBBBW  (all whites moved to the right)
```

The `B W` which is at the outer left is just a subinstance of the original problem and can be interchanged

```
W BWWW...WWWBBB...BBBBW
```

Now all the whites can continue moving to the left and we do the same (symmetrical) process in the right side as well.

In the last step we end up with

```
WWWWW...WWB WBB...BBBBB
```

Those (outer) misplaced pegs is a sub-instance of the original problem of size $1$ and can be interchanged.
Hence we can do the interchange for $B = 5$ and $W = 5$ or in general any number of pegs $B=n$ and $W=n$

Comment: Hi Jim! Your solution is indeed correct.

Comment: @AndrewYung: Are there any gaps? Could this be formalized more/better?

Comment: Other than the "literal" ones in the problem you just proved, none haha. One might even go as far as to say your proof is an example of a very well done induction. :)

Comment: @AndrewYung:Ah that is good to hear!Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if there is any better way to visually depict the solutions

Comment: Usually in this game the pieces are only allowed to move/jump forwards, and the solution for that can be proved with induction too. There is a nice way to visualise this solution: Instead of having the peg locations in a straight line, put them in a zig-zag, sawtooth arrangement. A move is then a diagonal shift, and a jump a horizontal one. In the solution the two colours simply pass each other along the parallel lines.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: I wasn't aware of that rule. Although I did figure out that due to the backward moves my approach must be sub-optimal i.e. has more moves than required. Is the proof for the only forward moves difficult?

Comment: Once you know what the solution looks like, and really understand how it works, it is easy to prove by induction that it works for any length. The trick is to split the solution into three phases: From the start position to a position with the pieces alternating and the empty space at one end, from that to the mirror position with the empty space at the other end, and from there to the solved state. The third phase is the same as the first but mirrored and in reverse. The first and second phases can each be proved by induction.